# Perl context - why is return value not the same as $1?

Tags: regex, perl

I found that in some situations that the return value from a regex match is True and other times the return value in the ()

eg, I am finding all text up to a semi-colon:

```
my $blop = "some;different;fields";
if(some expression)
{
    my $blip = $blop =~ /([^;]+)/;
}
```

I expected $blip eq "some", but it is 1 (or TRUE) return value from the check.

$1 contains my desired result, so I can write:

```
$blop =~ /([^;]+)/;
my $blip = $1;
```

But that's inefficient.  I am sure that in other scenarios that the return is the bracketed result, what is different here?

Answer (score 9):

If you give the regex list context, it returns the captures in the list:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $blop = "some;different;fields";
my($blip) = $blop =~ /([^;]+)/;

print "$blip\n";
print "$1\n";
```

That prints 'some' twice.

In a scalar context, a regex returns true if it matched and false otherwise (which is why you can use them in conditions).  Add these two lines to the code above:

```
my $blup = $blop =~ /([^;]+);([^;]+)/;
print "$blup : $1 : $2\n";
```

and the extra code prints:

```
1 : some : different
```